# CodeIgniter Facebook URL Errors

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, redirect

I'm currently having issues with my Facebook appliation being ported to CodeIgniter from raw PHP.

The issue I'm having is that I have a CodeIgniter driven redirect:

```
function signedin()
{
    echo "signed in?";
}

function save_user_data()
{
    $insert['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
    $this->db->insert('users', $insert);
    redirect('signedin');
{
```

Based upon how all of the URLs are setup, the method `save_user_data` is accessed by the following:

`www.apps.facebook.com/my_app_name/save_user_data`

I'd thought the redirect would go to the following:

`.../my_app_name/signedin`

Instead I receive the following error:

`The URL http://apps.facebook.com/my_app_name/index.php/signedin is not valid.`

It's adding in the `index.php` somewhere. Is this a Facebook addition, or a CodeIgniter one?

The URLs that access this from the web are being changed. I'm using the default controller in CodeIgniter, so my Facebook canvas page is set as the following:

`www.mywebsite.com/index.php/welcome/`

Though `www.mywebsite.com/index.php/welcome/signedin` is the page I want to redirect to.

I cannot figure out where this error has originated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ended up just changing $config[‘index_page’] = “”; That did it. Sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing $config[‘index_page’] = “”; That did it. Sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 0):

index.php/controller is how CI works .. so when u redirect index.php is a given .. unless u put in the full path

maybe use mod_rewrite to adjust ur urls?